# ROOT: sum root files with hadd with weights

Tags: histogram, root-framework

I have two root files (file1.root and file2.root) containing many histograms and I would like to merge them in one histogram (file3.root). I would generally use `hadd` for this, but this time I would like to multiply each file by a weight (so each histogram inside the file).

Is there a simple way to use hadd with weights?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `hadd` is made for that use case. It's just for summing outputs of embarrassingly parallel processing.

If your weights are all integer, you could just read the files in multiple times as a hack. **BUT** that will only get the bin contents right, not the bin errors. (Filling once with the weight 5 is not the same as filling five times with the weight 1.)

But I'm afraid the only proper solution is to write an application for your use case. I guess it depends on your actual use case if you're better off with a simple program written from scratch or recycling the hadd source https://github.com/root-project/root/blob/master/main/src/hadd.cxx ?